# postdoc positions by countries

Tags: postdocs

I would like to categorize the research destinations by countries. In the level of postdoc positions, let consider three categories, the first one includes US, UK, Canada and Australia, second one includes (West) European countries and the third category consists of China, Brazil, eastern European countries and India. We know that the first category is a popular destination for postdoc applicants. I would like to know whether a postdoc position in third category has any weight from perspective of academia? I know this is a general question and it depends on many factors, more specifically, list of publications.

Comment: The question is asking whether having a postdoc position in a non-Western European country or Commonwealth has any weight from the perspective of academia. It is by no definition a shopping question.

Comment: Sorry but the premise of the question is flawed in many ways: one can find low-quality institutions in the first group and high-quality institutions in the last group; an institution can be good in one field and bad in another; and more importantly somebody can do a brilliant postdoc anywhere and a terrible one anywhere as well. There are simply too many parameters for answering such a question in any meaningful way.

Comment: So the only possible answer to this question is: yes a postdoc anywhere can have academic weight... but that doesn't help with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are strong research groups and weak research groups within all the categories of countries you mentioned. The weight of the postdoc period depends on who you are working with and what you accomplish.

Doing a postdoc in a particular country might make it easier to find a position there; going abroad at some point in one's academic career will make it easier to find a position in some countries.